# Statistical difference of a categorical variable among two different years

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have a categorical variable that encodes the answers of a certain population to particular question.

Each respondent can give multiple answers.
Which statistical test do I need to perform to check if the difference in the number (or perhaps better percentage) of people that gave a particular answer is statistically significant (e.g. in 2021 69 people gave the answer 3 23.3%, ~2% less than in 2019 for which the rate was 25,5%... is that decline significant?)

```
                  2019 (counts)      2021 (counts)   
    Answer_1       100                 70
    Answer_2        90                 60
    Answer_3        79                 60
    Answer_4        10                 10 
    Answer_5        30                 69
```

Comment: If there is no ordering between answers (so that answer 3 is not "in the middle" and answers 1 and 5 are not "extreme"), I would go for a Chi-squared test.

Comment: No there is no order.... Chi-squared using the years as groups or the answers ? For me it is interesting to know whether there are differences between the same answer in two different years

Comment: Is the question, that *fewer* people answered e.g Answer_3, or is it that the *distribution of responses* is different between years ?  That is, 309 people responded in 2019 and 269 people responded in 2021.  That's not the question, right ?   Also --- important --- Are the *Answers* mutually exclusive ?

Comment: The question is: in 2019 25.5% of the respondents gave answer 3. In 2021 22.3% of the respondents gave answer 3. Is this decline significative? The answers are not mutually exclusive. A respondent can give multiple answers

Comment: Because the answers aren't mutually exclusive, you won't be able to use a chi-square test of association on the whole table. ...  It sounds like you want to treat each Answer separately relative to the total responses for the year.  You can use a test for two proportions.

Comment: However, you probably want to base that on the total number of *respondents* for each year.  That is, if there 100 responses in 2019, the proportion of respondents that chose Answer 3 in 2019 is 79 / 100 or 79 % .  (Not 79 / 309 ).

Comment: Chi-squared is a test on independence of two categorical variables, thus you don't have to choose one of the two variables as "group". However, I had given as granted that you couldn't give multiple answers; with multiple answers, as pointed out by Sal Mangiafico, the Chi-squared test is not valid anymore.

Comment: I agree with Sal Mangiafico: here you can perform 5 different tests on equality of proportions (and possibly think of a global test, whose null hypothesis would be that proportions are equal between the 2 years for each answer), but you have to know the total number of responders to do so.